# Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0) even after upgrade MariaDB version

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, mariadb

i have used xampp that include mariadb 10.1.x on windows pc. 
As i need to use recursive cte function which needed at least mariadb 10.2.x, i try look for new xampp but not found any that have mariadb 10.2, so i do install mariadb 10.3 manually on xampp mysql folder. it worked and show me right version of mariadb [10.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq6mU.jpg) but when i try it on query it still return me error "Unrecognized statement near WITH" any suggestion to fix my problem?

```
WITH RECURSIVE category AS (
    SELECT NULL AS col
    UNION
    SELECT "THIS NEVER SHOWS UP" AS col FROM category
)
```

*edited
even with example query from mariaDB [doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPL3U.jpg) it still give me same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKPIo.jpg)

Comment: You almost there [Recursive CTE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/)

Comment: You never use that CTE...this by itself is a syntax error, because there is no actual query.  MariaDB 10.2.2 or later in fact should support recursive CTE.  Just take the documentation as an example to get started.

Comment: sorry my bad providing random query on post.. edited my question there with mariaDB doc example but still same error not recognized with statement

Comment: Seems more a problem related to installation and configuration, not to programming. I think therefore this question is more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would expect "...syntax error...", not "Unrecognized statement..."  Where are you running it?  Are you using PHP?  If so, let's see the statement invoking it.

Comment: the problems is "WITH" keywords is not recognized by xampp even i install required version of maria DB.. so its a no for syntax problems.. more to install can config problem like trincot stated

Answer (score 3):

**WITH** keyword (Common Table Expressions) are not yet supported by phpmyadmin's sql parser yet
can check it [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165).

Until that to use the same syntax use other alternatives tools like sequal pro for macos etc or sql command line itself.